# php form submission to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I have a registration form. In the database, the username and email are unique index. When the form submits and username or email are already present in the database, the values are not inserted. I want to notify the user that the values were not inserted. How can i do this?

**HTML**

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="reg" onsubmit='return validate();'>
    Company Name: 
    <input type="text"  class="inputs" name="name" id="name" /><br />
    Email:
    <input type="text" class="inputs" name="email" id="txtEmail" /><br />
    User name:
    <input type="text"  class="inputs"  name="uname" id="uname"/><br />
    Password:
    <input type="password" class="inputs" name="pass" id="pass1"/><br />
    Conferm Password:
    <input type="password" class="inputs" name="cpass"  id="pass2"/><br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="button" />
</form>
```

**register.php:**

```
include ("db.php"); 
if (isset($_POST['register'])) { 
    echo $name = ($_POST["name"]); 
    echo $email = ($_POST["email"]); 
    echo $uname = ($_POST["uname"]); 
    echo $password = ($_POST["pass"]); 
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO company_profile(user_name, password, company_name, email, phone, country, activation_string) VALUES ('$uname','$password','$name','$email','','','')"); 
}
```

Comment: first check if tue username exists, if it does, then just give the user a message...

Comment: What does your PHP code look like so far?

Comment: include ("db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

echo $name = ($_POST["name"]);
echo $email = ($_POST["email"]);
echo $uname = ($_POST["uname"]);
echo $password = ($_POST["pass"]);




mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO company_profile(user_name, password, company_name, email, phone, country, activation_string) VALUES ('$uname','$password','$name','$email','','','')");


}

Comment: Plase add `register.php` to your question. Perhaps [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) will help you.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection. Please take a look at [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 3):

**Sweet And Short **

First check that username or email is exist or not using **`select`** query  if resulting is 0 (it means not exists), **`Insert`** query will run ahead

```
<?php 
   if($_POST['register']){   
      $uname = $_POST['uname'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $name= $_POST['name'];
      $pass= $_POST['pass'];
      $result =  mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where email_id = "'.$email.'" or username = "'.$uname.'" ');
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
          echo "Username or email already exists.";
       }else{
         $query = mysqli_query($con , 'INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (`email_id`, `username`,`name`,`pass`) VALUES("'.$email.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$uname.'","'.$name.'", "'.$pass.'")');

         if($query){
            echo "data are inserted successfully.";
         }else{
          echo "failed to insert data.";
         }
     } 
}
  ?>
```

Comment: nope, I removed comment already ;)  I'm used to object oriented mysqli  style, but offcourse procedural style will work too I guess... You have my vote! But as @Marcel Balzer already commented, use prepared statements to prevent injection

Answer (score 0):

The query method would return true or false, depending on if the row has been inserted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code

```
    include ("db.php"); 
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) 
    { 
    echo $name = ($_POST["name"]); 
    echo $email = ($_POST["email"]); 
    echo $uname = ($_POST["uname"]);
    echo $password = ($_POST["pass"]);
   $var = mysqli_query('SELECT * from company_profile where email_id = "'.$email.'" or username = "'.$uname.'" ');
$num = mysqli_num_rows($var);
if($num==0)
{
    $result = INSERT INTO company_profile(user_name, password, company_name, email, phone, country, activation_string) VALUES ('$uname','$password','$name','$email','','','');
    $res = mysqli_query($result);
        if($res)
        {
        echo "Records Inserted Successfully!!";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Records Inserted Failed!!";
        }
}
else
{
echo "User with the Details Already exists!!"
}
     }
```