# Php form submission-Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

include ("db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

echo $name = ($_POST["name"]);
echo $email = ($_POST["email"]);
echo $uname = ($_POST["uname"]);
echo $password = ($_POST["pass"]);


 $result =  mysql_query($con,'SELECT * from company_profile where user_name = "'.$uname.'" or email = "'.$email.'"');
       if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
          echo "Username or email already exists.";
       }else{
           $query = mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO company_profile(user_name, password, company_name, email, phone, country, activation_string) VALUES ('$uname','$password','$name','$email','','','')");

         if($query){
            echo "data are inserted succesfully.";
         }else{
          echo "failed to insert data.";
         }
     }

}


  ?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="reg" onsubmit='return validate();'>
                 Company Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input type="text"  class="inputs" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                 Email:     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input type="text" class="inputs" name="email" id="txtEmail" /><br />
                 User name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input type="text"  class="inputs"  name="uname" id="uname"/><br />
                  Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type="password" class="inputs" name="pass" id="pass1"/><br />
                  Conferm Password: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type="password" class="inputs" name="cpass"  id="pass2"/><br /><br /> 
                 <input type="submit" value="Register" class="button" />
                  </form>
```

Trying to check whether username or email exist in database if yes alert user if no insert values to db. The code doesn't work for me. no error no echo no insertion. any solution?

Comment: can you add the html form for this ?

Comment: what is exactly not working, except that you are highly vulnerable to injections

Comment: Is your database connection successful created?

Comment: What if `$_POST["name"]` or `$_POST["email"]` or `$_POST["uname"]` or `$_POST["pass"]` is not set ? you are not checking those, why ?

Comment: unrelated, but whats with those non-breaking-spaces man ?

Comment: @sanketh this is how people new to web development design their forms :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php form submission to mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011056/php-form-submission-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first check `isset($_POST['register'])` is always false because there is no input in your form with the `name="register"`

and also you chould fix your query , $con should be the second parametre.

and keep in mind that your code is highly vulnerable don't publish this on a server except of your localhost

Comment: `$con` should not be first parameter according to the official `mysql_query` doc

Answer (score 4):

You have no field with name `register`

Regarding this

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
```

It will never evaluate to true.

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="button" />
```

needs name attribute `name="register"`

In addition:

http://php.net/mysql_query

You have wrong order of arguments. However, using mysql_* is highly NOT encouraged. It is an obsolette database API with a lot of vulnerabilities. Switch to mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$result =  mysql_query('SELECT * from company_profile where user_name = "'.$uname.'" or email = "'.$email.'"',$con);
```

[mysql_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp)

Answer (score 0):

as you are using mysql_query, the link identifier should be second paramater

```
$result =  mysql_query('SELECT * from company_profile where user_name = "'.$uname.'" or email = "'.$email.'"', $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating yourself...

First of all, to check the user, just do this when form submits:

```
var_dump(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select bla bla where username=`{$_GET['username']}`")));
//by bla bla i mean primary key, don't select *, affects performance.
```

Also, please see this, you have an error in your syntax... take a look at the right parameters for mysql_query

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

After you set your queries and do the above test and figure out if its good or not, you can cut the 3-4 lines you have above in 1 if line like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select bla bla where username=`{$_GET['username']}`"))) { //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Without $con in INSERT query

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_profile
                        (
                         user_name,    password, 
                         company_name, email,     
                         phone,        country, 
                         activation_string
                         ) 
                      VALUES 
                        (
                         '$uname',  '$password',
                         '$name',   '$email',
                         '',        '',
                         ''
                         )");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name to your input field and check for that:-

```
<input type="submit" name="register" value="register">
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" name="register">Register</buton>
```